# Automatic Test with Selenium - Log in and send email

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have been studying testing for 2 days and I am trying to make automatic test where a system have the below **Two steps**:

1. Log in into Email
2. Send a email

I completed first step and I have problem with second. After login, the system will **click button "Create Message"** but it **doesn't get clicked**. Window with new message can't display and test is failed.

I have tried in many ways. Please look at my code and screens below in links:

**Code:** https://pastebin.com/QELY8Cje

**Screen:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8muR.jpg

@edit

Password in code is wrong so don't try use it.

Comment: Can you try this two things: 1. Add wait for the element visible and 2. Try with this locator  "//*[@id=":gg"]/div/div" for compose button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set an implicit wait. 90% of the times the problem is a synchronization issue:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, When I opened the link (`http://gmail.com`) I found this page.

[Google Home Page](http://prntscr.com/ibby69)

> Before performing any actions you need **to click `SIGN IN` button**.

**Element :**

LinkText =  `Sign In`

**OR**

LinkText = `SIGN IN`

**OR**

css = `a[class='gmail-nav__nav-link gmail-nav__nav-link__sign-in']`

**OR**

xpath = `//a[@class='gmail-nav__nav-link gmail-nav__nav-link__sign-in']`

---

> Code should be like this from line num **`38`** :

```
 wd.get(url);
 wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='gmail-nav__nav-link gmail-nav__nav-link__sign-in']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(2000); // remove this after your code get run properly
 WebElement loginName = wd.findElement(By.name("identifier"));
```

[Sign In Page](http://prntscr.com/ibc4g6)

> After clicking on `SIGN IN`, browser will open this page and you can run your remain code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='COMPOSE']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@gh='cm']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```